# Unexpected T CONSTANT ENCAPSED STRING in CODE on line 2

Tags: php, mysql, blogs

Hello I am working on making a blog php script and I cant get it to work.
I keep getting a  error.

If it is useful I am using Microsoft WebMatrix 3.

```
<?php
Print "<div class=""post"">
     <h2 class=""title""><a href=""#"">" .$info['title'] ."</a>
         </h2><p class=""meta"">Posted by <a href=""#"">" .$info['name'] ."</a>".$info['date'] ."<div class=""entry""><p>".$info['post']"</p></div></div>"; ?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a basic syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP doesn't support double `"` marks as a method of escaping. You need to use a `\`:

```
print "<div class=\"post\">";
```

Even better, wrap the string in `'` characters, which won't interfere with them:

```
print '<div class="post">';
```

On a side note, `<p class="meta">` isn't closed in your HTML - have a look over it.